# $injector not working when using angular inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am learning `inheritance in AngularJS`, so I created an example to dig into it. From top to bottom its conveying the info as expected. But from child to parent its not. Following is the [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/) I am following which is using `$injector` . When I am using the same in my code it breaks, let me know what I am doing wrong here.

My whole code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Inheritance</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body { text-align: center;}
        div { border: 1px solid red; margin: 2px; padding: 2px;}
        div div { border: 1px solid green; margin: 2px; padding: 2px;}
        div div div { border: 1px solid blue; margin: 2px; padding: 2px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="frstCtrl">
        <p>I am <b>{{grandfather}}</b></p>
        <p><b>{{father}}</b> is my son.</p>
        <p><b>{{son}}</b> is my grandson.</p>
        <div ng-controller="secCtrl">
            <p>I am <b>{{father}}</b></p>
            <p><b>{{grandfather}}</b> is my father.</p>
            <p>{{son}} is my son</p>
            <div ng-controller="thrdCtrl">
                <p>I am <b>{{son}}</b></p>
                <p><b>{{father}}</b> is my father.</p>
                <p><b>{{grandfather}}</b> is my grandfather.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('frstCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector){
        $injector.invoke(thrdCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
        $injector.invoke(secCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
        $scope.grandfather = "Test GrandFather";
    }]);

    myApp.controller('secCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector){
        $injector.invoke(thrdCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
        $scope.father = "Test Father";
    }]);

    myApp.controller('thrdCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.son = "Test Son";
    }]);    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said how it's breaking but I'm assuming you're getting a ReferenceError with `secCtrl` and `thrdCtrl`?

If you look at the example in the tutorial you can see that they define a function called `CarController` that is then referenced in `BMWController` (via a closure):

```
function CarController($scope) {
    //...
}

function BMWController($scope, $injector) {
    $injector.invoke(CarController, this, {$scope: $scope});
    $scope.name = 'BMW';
}
```

You need to do something similar in your example to make it work.

For example, defining your function controllers as named functions and then setting them up in Angular should work:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('frstCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector', frstCtrl]);
function frstCtrl($scope, $injector){
    $injector.invoke(thrdCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
    $injector.invoke(secCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
    $scope.grandfather = "Test GrandFather";
}

myApp.controller('secCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector', secCtrl]);
function secCtrl($scope, $injector){
    $injector.invoke(thrdCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
    $scope.father = "Test Father";
}

myApp.controller('thrdCtrl', ['$scope', thrdCtrl]);
function thrdCtrl($scope){
    $scope.son = "Test Son";
}
```

If you're unclear on how it's possible to reference the named functions (`frstCtrl`, `srcCtrl`, `thrdCtrl`) "before" they're declared have a look at this blog post on variable and function hoisting: http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: Wow that fixes it ..as per the suggestion I will read this hoisting term..on stack u always learn something new everyday :)

Comment: just a point I need to ask..I a line you mentioned **CarController that is then referenced in BMWController (via a closure)** I thought closure is when a function is inside another function..then how its a case of closure here..please correct me if I am wrong with my perception

Comment: I think of a closure as referencing a variable "up the scope" (note: not related to Angular scopes) or referencing a variable that has been declared outside that function. For example, the `CarController` variable is declared outside `BMWController` but BMWController holds a reference to it. In this way `BMWController` forms a closure over the `CarController` variable.